# Number of rows in free acount of cartoDB

Tags: carto

How many rows in a table can have a free account?
and in the case of Magellan plan?

Answer (score 5):

It's not measured in "Rows" but in disk space.
http://cartodb.com/pricing

The free plan is 5MB, the Magellan plan is 50MB.

---

If you want to get fancy and try and figure out how many rows you can have, try this page - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933068(v=SQL.80).aspx - you'll need a decent idea as to your table structure/datatypes.